# Installing and Configuring SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins - needs clarifications

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am following the instructions at the url below to configure jenkins/sonar.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

and I come to that step

> 2. Scroll down to the SonarQube Runner configuration section and click on Add SonarQube Runner. [...]
>
> **If you don't see a drop down list** with all available SonarQube Runner versions but instead see an empty text field then **this is
>   because Jenkins still don't have downloaded required update center
>   file (default period is 1 day)**. You may force this refresh by
>   clicking 'Check Now' button in Manage Plugins >> Advanced tab.

The tutorial fails to mention how to fix this in the case the server is **not able to connect to the internet** (this would be the case for many or most companies!). The explanation provided "required update center file" is to vague IMO.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Jenkins server doesn't have access to the internet to download the update file, then it's not going to be able to auto-install the scanner either.

For your case, you'll need to install a scanner manually, then configure the path to it in Jenkins.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the prompt answer

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team Can you please provide a link with details  on how to setup and integrate with jenkins if the sonarqube server resides on a different server to jenkins (both behind proxy) ?  I just wasted a day to figure this out ... so aggravating. almost as though you dont want Enterprises to try your product.  Details will be greatly appreciated. I need to be able to run MSbuild Scanners that are on a remote Sonarqube server. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the right place @objectNotFound, but https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team -- thnks for the quick response!. there was no option to comment on that link ... is there a more appropriate site where I should be bringing this up ? Being new to Jenkins + SonarQube Iam afraid I need a more detailed document preferably a walkthrough that will leave nothing to my wild imagination. Appreciate your help

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube @objectNotFound